# Fallo al realizar git add -A

Tags: git, vscode, github, git-commit, git-add

> $ git add -Una advertencia: LF será reemplazado por CRLF en
> .gitignore. El archivo tendrá sus terminaciones de línea originales en
> la advertencia de su directorio de trabajo: LF será reemplazado por
> CRLF en package-lock.json. El archivo tendrá sus terminaciones de
> línea originales en la advertencia de su directorio de trabajo: LF
> será reemplazado por CRLF en package.json. El archivo tendrá sus
> finales de línea originales en la advertencia de su directorio de
> trabajo: LF será reemplazado por CRLF en src/App.js. El archivo tendrá
> sus terminaciones de línea originales en su directorio de trabajo
> error: 'proyect3-calculadora/' no tiene un compromiso verificado
> fatal: error al agregar archivos

---

Estoy aprendiendo a usar **git** en **Visual Studio Code** y al querer subir los cambios que he realizado al repositorio remoto me sale el error mencionado anteiormente, he buscado soluciones pero no he encontrado la forma de resolverlo.

Gracias

Comment: La mayoría de mensajes no son de error, sino una advertencia de que te va a cambiar los retornos de carro de LF a CRLF en ciertos archivos, pero sólo a la hora de guardarlos en el repositorio git. En tu sistema seguirán estando con los retornos de carro originales. Esto solo te afecta si compartes el repo con otros usuarios que usen linux o mac, o contigo misma si trabajas en otras máquinas. Si no, puedes ignorarlos. Solo el último mensaje es realmente un error

Comment: Respecto al último error ¿estás usando _submodules_? ¿Es un repo tuyo o uno que has bajado de algún lugar? En el segundo caso ¿puedes poner el enlace al original?

Comment: Por otro lado, los mensajes de advertencia y de error que has pegado ¿son los que te vuelca git, o los has traducido con alguna herramienta? La traducción no es muy buena ("compromiso" quiere decir "commit"? "verificado" quiere decir "checked out"?). No parece la localización oficial de git. Creo que ayudaría mucho más a resolver el problema si pudieras obtener los mensajes de error en inglés.

Comment: @abulafia Los de los submódulos, me salían mensajes así y busqué pero no logro entender que significa. El repositorio es mío solo que mientras buscaba he intentaba entender los comandos de git, cree un repositorio y ejecute el comando git clone, ya que pensaba que era necesario hacerlo para poder subir un proyecto (cosa que no es así).

Comment: Si lo traduje con el traductor de google el mensaje que me salía es "error: 'proyect3-calculadora/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed"